# (PHP) Search for parts of a string in a vector and return the value

Tags: php

I'm facing the following dilemma, I have a vector that is returned from the bank in the following format:

```
$vetor = array(0 => 'CR:9090909090909', 1 => 'TR:9090909090909', 2 => 'CP:9090909090909', 3 => 'TP:9090909090909');
```

I would like to know how to check if in an indeterminate index it contains one of the example codes "CR:" if it has, remove the "CR:" from the value leaving only the value after this code in the case "9090909090909", remembering that this interaction will be in one foreach for each index of the vector.

Comment: Do you want to modify the existing array by replacing `CR:9090909090909` with `9090909090909`, or only to find and return the code (codes?) corresponding to `CR`?

Comment: Find from the identifier `CR:` that comes before the number, after finding, remove the identifier `CR:` leaving only the number `9090909090909`, remembering that the number `9090909090909` is dynamic only `CR:` is fixed .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose from two variants.

a) Finding and extracting the single `CR` code value from `$vector` array.

```
function getCode($vector, $type) {
  foreach ($vector as $typeAndCode) {
    list($type1, $code1) = explode(":", $typeAndCode);
    if ($type1 === $type) return $code1;
  }
  return false;
}
$code = getCode($vector, "CR");
```

b) Writing the extracted `CR` code value directly into the existing `$vector` array. (I don't suppose you will need this variant, but your question wasn't very clear about it.)

```
$vector = array_map(function ($typeAndCode) {
  list($type, $code) = explode(":", $typeAndCode);
  return $type === "CR" ? $code : $typeAndCode;
}, $vector);
```